# understanding mutual information score of two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, scikit-learn, mutual-information

I am unable to understand how does the `from sklearn.metrics import mutual_info_score` package works?

so I have a `list` which is representative of the `arms` of a maze the `numbers` can be `between 1-8`.  But the numbers don't have weightage and all are `equal`, they just represent the arm number. They are from two different conditions let's say `A` and `B`.

Suppose the arms visited in condition A, are stored in `list_a` and in condition, B are stored in `list_b`.

I want to find out if there is any mutual information between the two conditions, say if `list_a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` and `list_b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` then `mutual information = 1` and if `list_a = [1,2,3,4]` and `list_b = [5,6,7,8]` then `mutual information = 0`.

I use this code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mutual_info_score
list_a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
list_b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

mutual_info = mutual_info_score(list_a, list_b)
```

however, I get different values than I expected for `mutual information= 1.94`
I am not able to understand how it computes `mutual_info_score`?

is this the correct way to compute mutual_info?

PS: I am not sure where to post this but since it has Python modules am putting it here.

edit: list_a and list_b could be of variable lengths so comapring length is not desired.

Comment: `mutual_score_info` is designed to be used with lists of lists -- a series of collections, not just a series of samples.  Can't you just turn these into sets, do an intersection, and compute `similarity = len(intersection) / max(len(list_a),len(list_b))`?

Comment: no so lengths could vary, if list_a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] and list_b = [1,2,3,4] there is still some similarity and hence some mutual information, if the items are exactly same in the two lists then there is some mutual information  between these two lists.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this come pretty close to what you're after?  This essentially computes the ratio between the length of the union of the two sets and the sum of the lengths of the two sets.

```
def sim(list_a,list_b):
    seta = set(list_a)
    setb = set(list_b)
    union = seta | setb
    both = len(seta)+len(setb)
    return (both-len(union)) / max(len(seta),len(setb))

print(sim([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]))
print(sim([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7]))
```

Output:

```
1.0
0.0
```

Comment: lists of length could vary. We just need to compare the elements using the concept of information transfer or similarity as used in mutual_info_score.

Comment: This works just fine with lists of differing lengths, as shown by the second example.  Now, if you have some predefined metric of similarity, perhaps you should say that.  Clearly, the metric has to be based on some ratio between "number that are the same" and "number that are different".

Comment: this sounds good but what happens if  a list has multiple numbers repeating, say list_a = [1,2,3,4,5] and list_b = [1,1,2,2,3] ? I am not sure if this is correct but, wont finding out entropy or mutual info something more based on Probability would be a more comprehensive approach in terms of information ?